Laravel 11: restricting user access to 'Sites' using gates and policies
I'm attempting to restrict users from viewing 'Sites' assigned to other users in Laravel 11. Users should only be able to see the 'Sites' assigned to them. I've been trying to implement this using Laravel's gates and policies, but I'm encountering some difficulties.
Here's the SitePolicy class:
namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Site;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response;

class SitePolicy {
    public function view(User $user, Site $site): bool {
        dd('ihhhh');
    } 
}

Here's the route I'm using:
Route::get('/view/{id}', 'view')->name('sites.view')->can('view', 'site');

And here's the AppServiceProvider class:
use App\Models\Site;
use App\Policies\SitePolicy;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider { 
    public function register(): void {  }

    public function boot(): void  {   
        Gate::guessPolicyNamesUsing(function (string $site) {   });
    }
}

I've attached the policy, routes, and AppServiceProvider code for reference. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

can you share the full route file?

And your actual policy class?

can you try it like this : Route::get('/view/{site}',  'view' )->name('sites.view')->can('view', 'site'); thanks to the route binding you will get an instance of site and it will be passed to your policy

@DevNewbie I've updated my answer... Check the new controller definition.

"If you would like to define your own policy discovery logic, you may register a custom policy discovery callback using the Gate::guessPolicyNamesUsing method." ... why do you think you need to customize the discovery? and also this returns nothing, there is no logic for the discovery and nothing to return, so there is no discovery now

But atleast the method would just return something, it is not even showing my dd() or die()

@miken32 Thanks for replying , I have added my policy class in the question

@miken32 Did not work, still showing '403 Unauthorized access'

did you added the ? in here public function view(?User $user, Site $site): bool { ? because 403 means that you are rejected by a policy or a middleware

This is not your actual policy class, I hope. You are returning nothing, it's just a call to dd()???

@miken32 Yes, but it should show my dd()nresponse if it is coming inside that function

Make sure everything is correctly defined:

The Controller is correctly referred in the route definition:
Route::get('/view/{id}', [SiteController::class, 'view'])->...->can('view', 'site');


The controller method is correctly type-hinted:
class SiteController {
    public function view(Site $id) {...}
}


The policy method matches 'view', from the can helper in the route definition:
Routes file:
Route::get('/view/{id}', 'view')->...->can('view', 'site');

Policy:
class SitePolicy {
    public function view(User $user, Site $site): bool {
        return ...;
    } 
}


The user is logged in or, alternatively, that the policy allows guests to proceed:
class SitePolicy {
    // Make the user optional, allowing guests
    public function view(?User $user, Site $site): bool {
        return ...;
    } 
}




Thanks for the reply back. I have added bboth the changes but still it show '403 This action is unauthorized'

@DevNewbie after fixing the routes as I wrote, try to remove this part:
Gate::guessPolicyNamesUsing(function (string $site) {   });

removed the part but no luck :(

the name of the route parameter has no direct relationship to anything ... they just need to tell the middleware which parameter to use ... the typehinting on the action is how the system knows what model to use

@lagbox I was not aware of that. I'll test it and edit my answer

@lagbox thanks for replying but I did not understand, all I want is to just call my policy functions which are not being called now.
